# Blender Shader Node interpolation

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders, color, interpolation

I'm trying to color a cube with its own position in 3D space, which works well with the shader node setup I have, but only sets the colors for the vertices. However, I would like this to interpolate across the faces, so that the position is not only correct at the vertices but between as well. Is there some shader magic to get this working?

Img. of my cube and the colored vertices (note how the upper right corner correctly is set to (1,1,1 = white) but that it's not interpolating across the face middle):
[image]

Comment: It's not that it's interpolating incorectly (and it's not really interpolating anyways, not like you think, it's looking at the position of each sample).  It's that the 0,0,0 world position is in the middle of your cube, and the negative positions are getting clamped to 0,0,0.  You have to decide what you want it to do if position is less than zero or greater than 1.  Because your monitor will never be able to display color outside the 0,1 range.

Comment: You're right, ofc I would have to do some kind of normalization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get the result you want by plugging the **generated** texture coordinates from the vertex positions of your cube in the **Texture Coordinate** node instead of the **Geometry** node.

Here's the result :
[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot! Bonus question: do you know how I can unwrap this shading effect, and bake it into an image? Or could you give me some pointers as to what keywords to look up ?

Comment: I tried baking using the **Cycles** render engine and trying to use the **Emit Bake Type** but I have an error that says that there's no active image found in my material even if I have the position plugged in. Tell me if you find. This other post helped a little : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100731/how-to-bake-a-position-map-in-blender

Comment: I just found out that this is called "render baking" and "texture baking". Thanks guys!

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Cycles to be honest. If I had to do it, I would probably import the mesh inside of Substance Painter and bake the position in it.